# How is "flat" defined in SAGA

Tags: saga, terrain

SAGA has a feature that determines flats. Does anybody know how they define a flat? If I start with a raster, each pixel is flat - so it has to be more sophisticated than that. I would like to be adjust the thresholds to consider it a flat if two pixels are within 15m vertical of each other. Would that be possible? How?

Comment: Why not just threshold a slope raster then? For example, if 15 m is your vertical difference below which you say it's flat and r is your grid resolution, then the threshold slope = atan(15.0 / r) * 180 / 3.14159. Every cell with a slope (in degrees) less than this threshold would be, by your definition, 'flat'. I'm guessing that your grid resolution must be pretty big if a 15 m difference in height is considered flat!

Comment: Are you loading a valid DEM?

Comment: Thank you WhiteboxDev - yes, that would work. The grid resolution is pretty coarse - each tile is 250m, so 15m on 500m is flat enough for what I need.

Comment: BradHards, I am not sure I understand your question - I am pretty sure it is valid for what I am trying to do. The DEM came in an ascii xyz format of non-gridded data. I converted it to gridded data and generated a raster with each pixel being about 250m - it is pretty coarse and I can refine it, but not sure that that would change the procedure - would it?

Comment: @PeterB I'm glad that would work. I figured you were dealing with fairly large grid resolutions because at the scales that I usually work, a 15 m drop over 2 m would be one heck of a cliff! Good luck with your applications.